# Use OEM Encoding without RegisterProvider

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

I am making a class library for SQL. One of the classes has a function where I need to get `Encoding.GetEncoding(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)`. Of course everything works if there is code before that line:

```
System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

But the problem is that to use `System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider` I need to download Nuget package which has a mountain of dependencies and that would be along with my dll. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page.  You need to use one of the encoding for OEM at following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers.  You can read file GetAllBytes and then convert to string using Encoding.GetEncoding("Either name or number").GetString(byte[] bytes)

Comment: You're targeting an old version of .NET Core.  If you're targeting .NET Core 3.0 or higher, you don't need the NuGet package to be able to use `CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance`.